# Storing result of cat as different index values

Tags: bash, cat, array

i have parsed a file using `cat`and now I want to save the result of it in array.

```
var1=$(cat abc.txt | grep .........)
```

and the var1 looks like

```
33 23 51 11 16 43 5 50 4 2 12 29 32 28 47 41 7 20 38 45 49 26 22 10 44 9 19 27 46
```

1.I want each value to be stored as array variables but when I do this all result of '`cat` is stored at index 0 of `var1`

How to save each value as different index?

Comment: There are several ways to produce an array. One of them is `var_arr=( $(grep … abc.txt) )`

Comment: Second is to use special command like `read -a`, `readlines|mapfile`

Comment: Third — add to array in a loop: `for m in $var1 ; do var_arr[${#var_arr[*]}]=m ; done`

Comment: @Costas, I have tried the Third way to but that is not working, if I use it and then to check if I check `echo ${var_arr[0]}`then i see `m` although if i add `echo $m`  tiger u see that m is a number.

Comment: Sorry, I have miss `$` mark. Should be `var_arr[${#var_arr[*]}]=$m`

Comment: @Costas, I have tried with `$` before... but still its giving me the same results. i.e after this update if I check `echo ${var_arr[0]}`then again I see `m`

Comment: It is result of previous try. You should cleen array by `unset var_arr` before.

Comment: @Costas, its working now. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30473/discussion-between-umar-and-costas).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash the `readarray` builtin can store the values in arrays:

```
readarray arr < <(grep "pattern" abc.txt)
```

This will create an array called `arr` with the values given by the command `grep "pattern" abc.txt` (if they come in multiple lines, `readarray` appends them to the array):

```
echo ${arr[0]}
33
$ echo ${arr[10]}
12
$ echo ${arr[*]}
33 23 51 11 16 43 5 50 4 2 12 29 32 28 47 41 7 20 38 45 49 26 22 10 44 9 19 27 46
```

---

BTW: `cat file | grep ...` can be shortened to `grep ... file`, grep can also read files.

Comment: `read` puts into array 1 line (before first `\n`ewline) only

Comment: @Costas Isn't that what the user wants?

Comment: Suppose grep produce multiline output. In the case there is suitable echoing: `read -a arr < <(echo $(grep "pattern" abc.txt))`

Comment: @Costas now it supports multiline input.

Comment: @chaos, I am using Mac OS and when i enter `readarray arr < <(grep "pattern" abc.txt)` the bash shell becomes super slow .. and if i close the shell then every things gets back to normal.. any idea why this is happening

Comment: @Umar What exactly does the grep command return? Just the line in your question or is there more?

Comment: @chaos, it returns the line but don't return to to prompt.

Comment: @Umar That why grep continues to search for more and therfore the command waits until grep is done. If you want to exit after the first match, OSX's grep has the `-m` flag (see: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/grep.1.html). Use `grep -m 1 "pattern" file`.

Comment: Please note `readarray` == `mapfile`